# How to recover Windows 8 partition in dual boot?

Tags: linux, windows-8, partitioning, fedora, fedora-21

I've installed fedora 21 in my computer, i've made the partitons correctly, appears the boot menu and starts correctly in fedora, but when i try to boot in windows appears this error:

```
Windows Boot Manager
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software might be the problem. To fix the problem:
Insert your Windows Installation disc and restart your computer
....
File: \Boot\BCD
Status: 0X0000225
Info: The boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors
```

I can mount the windows partition correctly, and i haven't made changes in windows filesystem. Is there a way, where can i restore the dual boot without erase my linux partition?

All the solutions i've founded are in Ubuntu or debian